# Converting decimal to long while allowing overflow

Tags: c#, .net

So I'm trying to do an unchecked casting of a decimal (which is used as a "holder" for any number, could be integers, could be floating point numbers, etc).
Problem with C# is that it doesn't allow overflowing when converting a decimal to an integer type, even though overflow is acceptable and expected. The unchecked context only works for integer types, not for decimals, so I'm looking for the best way to achieve this.

Here's my current method (for Int32 as an example), and if you have any suggestions, please write it down.

```
    private static int ToInt32(decimal value)
    {
        if (value is < int.MinValue or > int.MaxValue)
        {
            decimal range = 1L + int.MaxValue - int.MinValue;
            value = ((((value - int.MinValue) % range) + range) % range) + int.MinValue;
        }
        return (int)value;
    }
```

With this, if I try to convert `2731498700m` to an Int32, I'll get `-1563468596` (instead of an OverflowException), which is exactly what I want.

Comment: Does that code do what it should? If so, this question better suites at codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you find, with your `if`, that `value` is outside the bounds, why don't you just `throw new OverflowException()`?

Comment: Because I didn't say that I want an exception, quite the contrary...

Comment: Ah, I was confused and misunderstood. I deleted an answer that was based on my misunderstanding.

Comment: Just checking if some savvy has a more elegant way to achieve this instead of this hacky stuff I used.

Comment: What is wrong with the simpler `private static int ToInt32(decimal value)
    {
        if (value is < int.MinValue or > int.MaxValue)
        {
            const decimal range = 1L + int.MaxValue - int.MinValue;
            value = (value - int.MinValue) % range + int.MinValue;
        }
        return (int)value;
    }`?

Comment: OK, it can still fail for inputs that are so negative that they stay negative after subtraction of `int.MinValue`. So not good enough.

Comment: Yup, already tried that and it failed on the negatives.

Comment: What about the `Convert.ToInt32(decimal value)` is that not working?

Comment: `Exceptions: OverflowException - value is greater than Int32.MaxValue or less than Int32.MinValue.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the fastest method I have found so far, based on the source of [Decimal.ToInt32](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Decimal.cs,777)

```
private static int ToInt32(decimal value)
{
    Span<int> buffer = stackalloc int[4];
    decimal.GetBits(decimal.Truncate(value), buffer);
    return buffer[3] < 0 ? -buffer[0] : buffer[0];
}
```

---

Discovered a better method:

```
private static int ToInt32_1(decimal value)
    => (int)(Int128)value;
```

Comment: Now that is an interesting method. Got any for sbyte, short and long?

Comment: Please check the second, I think it can solve all of these types.

Comment: Nothing is going to beat going via a cast to `Int128` (which clearly can hold values of greater absolute value than `System.Decimal`, so cannot lose the magnitude), in clarity.

Comment: That's genius. Gotta admit, I had no idea Int128 was a thing. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `Int128` is new, from .NET 7 from November 2022.